# How to find the color of a view

Tags: android, android-elevation

I have a multi pane view: much like this:

[image]

The way I got this is by using elevation:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
```

That scroll view is the detail view on the right.  Android is assigned a darker background on my list view on the left to 'show' the elevation.  Which is great, view looks perfect.  However I want to highlight the selected item in the list.

List View:

Selected state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/some_color" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

My problem is I need to define some color and I want to make it a little darker than the color of the items in the list.  However I am not 100% sure what that color really is.

Can I find that by debugging?  Or better yet does anyone know what elevation is really doing to that views color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android isn't actually coloring the background differently based on elevation; the only effect an elevation attribute has is showing a shadow on 5.x devices. It just looks darker because you gave the `ScrollView` a white background and the default background of an Activity is an off-white color. If you want to determine that color, I'd recommend simply taking a screenshot and using an app to see what color those pixels are; I find Color Picker works very well. If you want that background color to be consistent everywhere, I'd manually set your `ListView`'s background to that color.

Comment: awesome, very helpful!  There has got to be a way to grab those colors from somewhere though right?  Either debugger or looking in android resource files.

Comment: The default Activity background can vary from device to device and version to version, so there's no place that it's universally defined. Again, the best way to figure out what the color is is to take a screenshot and then extract the color using any one of the many tools out there designed for that.